# Clear 5 empty TDs with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic table being filled, and I know I shouldn't do it this way, but how would you go about finding 5 empty TDs in a row, and hiding them? So, if row contains 5 empty TDs, do not show the TDs.

I want to remove every instance of `<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>` in the DOM. Not just the first.

I just want the 5 empty TDs to go away, not all empty TDs

Comment: Is there only 5 `tds` per row, or could there be more?

Comment: There would only be 5. Another note is that I want to remove the TDs from the dom, not just clear the contents inside them.

Comment: So remove the row instead of the TDs?

Comment: No, just remove the 5 empty TDs.

Comment: ..but then you'd be left with an empty table row (`<tr></tr>`)?

Comment: That will leave any border of the TR

Comment: There are other TDs on the row that will always be filled. I just wanted to search the DOM for 5 empty TDs and remove them from the DOM.

Comment: So there are more tds on the row. Could you please be a little clearer and add an example of before and after? For example if you need the TDs to collapse or just be hidden - it is as far as I know not valid to remove them unless you modify the colspan on the rest of the cells. In one comment you want to remove them from the DOM and in another you want to hide them. Can you rewrite your question with all the scenarios mentioned so far? I have added two to your question

Comment: So something like this: http://jqueryminute.com/finding-immediately-adjacent-siblings/

Answer (score 5):

You can use `:empty` selector:

```
$('#yourtable tr td').filter(':empty').hide();
```

If you want to remove `tr` elements that have 5 empty `td` elements, you can use `filter` method:

```
$('#yourtable tr').filter(function(){
   return $(this).find('td:empty').length === 5
}).remove()
```

---

If you want to remove only first 5 empty td elements, you can use `slice` method:

```
$('#yourtable tr td').filter(':empty').slice(0, 5).remove();
```

Comment: @Eric Do you want to remove only first 5 elements? try the updated code.

Comment: I want to remove every instance of "<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>" in the DOM. Not just the first, I tried this and it cleared the first, so maybe if I loop through each tr?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Grab every row in your table
$('table#yourTable tr').each(function(){
  if($(this).children('td:empty').length === $(this).children('td').length){
    $(this).remove(); // or $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: This will clear all empty TDs though, I just want the 5 empty TDs to go away, not all empty TDs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd solve this strange request: http://jsfiddle.net/5ZGgx/

```
$(function()
{  
    $("table tr").each(function()
    {
        var emptyCells = $(this).find("td").filter(function()
        {
            return $.trim($(this).text()).length === 0;
        });

        if(emptyCells.length === 5)
        {
            emptyCells.hide();                
        }
    });
})​;
```