# Find Elements in DOM using Jquery and remove

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clear 5 empty TDs with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896979/clear-5-empty-tds-with-jquery)

I want to search the DOM for any instance (might be multiple) where the DOM contains specifically

```
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
```

and remove it in Jquery. Any help?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question, and get an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896979/clear-5-empty-tds-with-jquery

Comment: I didn't get an answer that worked... I though this might be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you constant string then you can remove it from html,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/xVyQM/)**

```
$('#tbl').html($('#tbl').html().replace('<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>', ''));
```

Comment: I have updated my answer this will work if string does not change.

Answer (score 0):

This  is new [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sechou/FPp3s/11/):

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

JS

```
$(function(){

    $.map($("td:empty"),function(elem,i){
        console.log(i);

        var length =5;
        var current = length;
        var $ptr = $(elem);

        while(current>=0){
            if ($ptr.next("td:empty").size() == 1){
                current = current -1;
                $ptr = $ptr.next("td:empty");

            }else{
                break;
            }   
        }
        if(current<= 1 ){ 
            $(elem).siblings("td:empty:lt("+length+")").remove();
            $(elem).remove();                                
        }

    });

});​
```

Comment: I don't want to clear all TDs, just where html = <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
var rows = $('tr').filter(function(){
                var that = $(this),
                    len = that.find('td').length;
                return that.find('td:empty').length == len && len == 5;
            });
```

References:

- [`:empty` selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Comment: I don't want to clear all TDs, just where html = <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>

Comment: Yes? Oh, I see, I saw the `remove()` used on another answer and thought I must've missed something in the question. That was since removed and the selectors/filter assigned to a variable for later access.